# change actionbar spinner textcolor

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How can i change the actionbar spinner textcolor. 
I have created it with xml file in menu folder.
When it shows dropdown its textcolor is white and i have changed it with custom adapter. but how to change textcolor when its close? please see the screenshot.
[image: today Jul02 is the spinner i want to change that black color to white]

Here is the menu xml file code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_map_spinner"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_spinner"  />

<item
    android:id="@+id/btnAction"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
    android:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
            android:title="@string/right_menu_settings"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/btnShare"
            android:title="@string/right_menu_Share"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/btnRate"
            android:title="@string/right_menu_rate"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/btnRemoveAds"
            android:title="@string/right_menu_remove"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/btnFeedback"
            android:title="@string/right_menu_feedback"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/btnMoreApps"
            android:title="@string/right_menu_more_apps"/>
        <!-- <item -->
        <!-- android:id="@+id/btnAddAppointment" -->
        <!-- android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" -->
        <!-- android:title="Add Appointment"/> -->
    </menu>
  </item>
 </menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To modify the color of text in the action bar, you need to override separate properties for each text element..**

refer to this link..

[Customize the Text Color](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomText)

**Custom Theme :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item> <!-- Change color here -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

This may help you..

Comment: thanks for your answer. You gave me the general one. but from all code i found there is 1 line of code which changed my spinner text color. it is  <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item> in main style

Answer (score 0):

1 line of code solved my problem. and here is the screen shot.

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
 <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
</style>
```

[image]